# When is a Torah scroll kosher?

Tags: sefer-torah

A Torah scroll that is damaged cannot be used.  But if the "good" parts of several Torah scrolls are stitched together, is the resulting scroll kosher?  Or does the fact that more than one scribe contributed to it render it unfit?

Comment: BTW, a damaged Torah does not automatically render it unusable. It demands exactly what type of damage is there.

Comment: Menumar. This is halachically unideal and should not be done lechatchila

Answer (score 2):

I have to find a source for this.

I have been a Torah reader for about 45 years. My current shul has been in existence for about 80 years. I can vouch for the fact that of the 6 usable Sifrei Torah that we have (and we do, indeed, use all 6 at some point during the year,) I know that 5 of them were pieced together from either other Sifrei Torah or were written by multiple scribes. Considering their age, it would be almost impossible for such Sifrei Torah NOT to have been written by multiple scribes. I read from them, and, between checking with the shul's rav and the sofer, whom I speak to a few times per year, they are definitely kosher.

As a reader, while I know that such Sifrei Torah could not exist without this "piecing", I can say that it can become distracting when the writing style changes in the middle of a parsha that I am reading. I deal with it, though.

I don't recommend such Sifrei Torah for a "beginner" Bar Mitzvah boy unless he is comfortable and is extremely capable.

Comment: This is menumar and shouldn't be done, at least lechatchila. The 'oleh has not made berachot levatalah, but such sefarim should not be used except bisha'at hadchak

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt No argument on that. In my shul, there's little choice in the matter. If you can find a source, please post as an answer. (Hope all is well with you.)